# Route ajax calls to path other than one mentioned while making the call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My project is build in C# MVC. Assume its hosted on **abc.com**.
Ajax call made for a resource for ex on **Controller:Home** and  **Method:ClientInfo** will be something as :

> url: '/Home/ClientInfo'

For Testing purpose I have deployed same project on assume **xyz.com/web**
In this case my Home page is xyz.com/web.
Now ajax calls made for the resource Controller:Home and Method:ClientInfo with the same ajax url '/Home/ClientInfo' is returning 404 Not Found.
Since the url should be something as

> url: '/web/Home/ClientInfo'

One way of handling this is I edit all ajax urls throughout the project which doesn't seems right way.
I have common Layout can I write code there in javascript to route all urls under directory '/web' or is there any other way ?

*Note : I don't have control on web.config of xyz.com to handle the calls and  write rules in there.

Please Suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could make a JavaScript file that exports the API routes and import it when you need the routes, so you have one point to change when needed.

**example ES6**

File called `routes.js` with API routes:

```
export const API = '/web/';
export const CLIENT_INFO_API = `${API}home/clientinfo`;
```

Then whenever you need to use the routes in other files:

```
//Import routes file
import * as ROUTES from 'routes.js';

//Use the routes
ROUTES.API
ROUTES.CLIENT_INFO_API
```

**example ES5**

File called `routes.js` with API routes:

```
var routes = {};
routes.API = '/web/';
routes.CLIENT_INFO_API = routes.API+'home/clientinfo';

module.exports = routes;
```

Then whenever you need to use the routes in other files:

```
//Import routes file
const ROUTES = require('routes.js');

//Use the routes
ROUTES.API
ROUTES.CLIENT_INFO_API
```